# Removing specific rows from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains two columns. One of the columns named 'steps' begins with single digit numbers. I wish to keep only those rows which contain the maximum value for each sequence. It will be clear with this example: Consider the **Dataframe 1** (as shown in figure), the sequences of first digit are as follows:

- 1
- 1 2 3 4
- 1 2 3
- 1 2

[image: Dataframe 1]

Hence, I just want to keep the row number 0, 4, 7, and 9. Because they contain the highest first digit under the column - 'steps' for each sequence.

Any help in this regard would be helpful. Here is the code to generate the dataframe, 'Energies' column is irrelevant:

```
copy = pd.DataFrame([(234, 1), (234, 1), (234, 2), (234, 3), (234, 4), (234, 1), (234, 2),
                     (234, 3), (234, 1), (234, 2)], columns=['Energies', 'steps'])
```

Comment: When dealing with dataframes, please post python code to reproduce it, to avoid each people trying to help to rebuild it locally

Comment: Code added to the question. Will keep in mind the same from the next time @azro.

Comment: What is the ordering? Is there an ordering? Since you mention sequences of steps.

Comment: Please add some expected output for your code example. Note that the code example is not too great, since energies will always be 234, and is thus not very distinctive for maximum values of steps (knowing which index values are expected will already help).

Comment: Is the next sequence guaranteed to start with a lower value of steps than the maximum of the sequence before? Will there only be one maximum value per sequence?

Comment: No, there is no order as such. It is just that you start iterating from the top, and suppose you are iterating the (i)_th row. If the number in the (i+1)_th row is greater than the one in the (i)th row, then you remove the (i)_th row and the same goes on. Sorry if I made it even more complex :/

Comment: "Is the next sequence guaranteed to start with a lower value of steps than the maximum of the sequence before? - NO. Will there only be one maximum value per sequence? - YES"

Comment: You should define an order, even if it's only the index. Otherwise, if there is no ordering, I should be able to shuffle the dataframe and still produce a result (which is likely not what you want).

Comment: So you say the next sequence of digits does *not* have to start with a lower value than the maximum of the previous sequence? How is that then not a continuation of the previous sequence; how are they separated? E.g., `1, 2, 3, 4` could be followed by `6, 7, 8`; I would say `8` is the maximum of a seven-digit sequence. Can you clarify?

Comment: Rather than saying: "next sequence of digits has to start with a lower value than the maximum of the previous sequence", we can say - "next sequence of digits has to start with a lower value than the maximum of the previous sequence, or with ```1```." Considering the case where the numbers are: ```1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4``` there are 3 sequences in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean mask:

```
>>> copy[copy['steps'].ge(copy['steps'].shift(-1, fill_value=-np.inf))]

   Energies  steps
0       234      1
4       234      4
7       234      3
9       234      2
```

Comment: @TapasviBhatt. I get it now (I hope). Is it what you expect?